# Pass data from DOM to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have a PHP-driven with a certain variable that I need to use as a part of dynamically generated page title. The page is being routed by AngularJS which is also handling the title. The DOM section where the variable is being output looks like this:

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="asApp">
   <head>
      <title ng-bind="title">PeppyBurro – Radical Spanish learning tips and tricks for the adventurous learner</title>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="mainController">
      <div id="main" style="min-height: 50em;">
         <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**BLOG.PHP**

```
<?php echo '<span class="someclass">' . $author . '</span>'; ?>
```

**ANGULAR CONTROLLERS**

```
var asApp = angular.module('asApp', ['ngRoute']);
asApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider
      .when('/blog/author/:lev2', {
            title: 'The PeppyBurro blog',
            templateUrl : 'pages/blog.html',
            controller  : 'blogController'
        })
}]);


asApp.controller('blogController', function($scope, $routeParams){});

asApp.run(['$rootScope', '$route', '$location', function($rootScope, $route, $location) {
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
      if(0 === $location.path().indexOf('/blog/author/')) { document.title = 'Posts by “' + $route.current.params['lev2'] + '” | ' + $route.current.title; }
   });
}]);
```

Each of these snippets have been highly abridged for the sake of brevity but you can see all the affected areas and the flow of logic I am implementing. As you can see, I am using the slug of the URL (through `:lev2`) to generate the title which gives the author's ID instead of actual name. The PHP variable (`$author`) contains the real name for the corresponding ID. My question is, how can I pass the value of this variable to the AngularJS `blogController` section so that it could be included in the dynamically-generated page title instead of the URL slug?

I tried using `ng-model`:

```
<?php echo '<span class="someclass" ng-model="authorname">' . $author . '</span>'; ?>
```

Then I replaced `lev2` with `authorname` in my controller like so:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
      if(0 === $location.path().indexOf('/blog/author/')) { document.title = 'Posts by “' + $route.current.params['authorname'] + '” | ' + $route.current.title; }
   });
```

This ran without any error; however, it rendered my title as "*Posts by undefined*" instead. Can someone please suggest a fix?

Comment: use a `resolve` in router to make api call to get author data. You are going to fight this app by trying to use php to dynamically render snippets....just use it like everyone else does as strictly a data api

Comment: this is one of the *very few* places where using `ng-init` was designed to be used.  However, mixing angular and php code together will quickly become confusing if it isn't used sparingly.  incidentally, your proposed solution won't work, because `ng-model` is only usable on `input` elements, you can't use `ng-model` to a `span` or a `div`, since they have no way to change the model value after it's been rendered.